# Looping over objects when giving attributes

Tags: java, loops, object, attributes

I know my code makes no sense, I'm just learning, and in doing so, trying to do a for-loop. See the comment in Main! When I a basic for-loop the names looses the ".gender" functionality! Seeking help!

```
public class Dog {


public String whatGender(String gender) {
    if (gender == "yes") {
        gender = "Male";
    } else {
        gender = "Female";
    }
    return gender;
}


public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Dog Kvist = new Dog("Vuf!", 8, "yes");
    Dog Snoop = new Dog("Doggy Dogg World!", 48, "yes");
    Dog Greta = new Dog("We need change now!", 17, "no");

    //How do I translate the next 3 lines to a for-loop? #StillLearning
    Kvist.gender = Kvist.whatGender(Kvist.gender);
    Snoop.gender = Snoop.whatGender(Snoop.gender);
    Greta.gender = Greta.whatGender(Greta.gender);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be by creating an array of `Dog`s and then looping over them using a for loop:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Dog Kvist = new Dog("Vuf!", 8, "yes");
    Dog Snoop = new Dog("Doggy Dogg World!", 48, "yes");
    Dog Greta = new Dog("We need change now!", 17, "no");

    Dog[] dogs = {Kvist, Snoop, Greta};

    //How do I translate the next 3 lines to a for-loop? #StillLearning
    for (int i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++)
    {
        dogs[i].gender = dogs[i].whatGender(dogs[i].gender);
    }
    // Kvist.gender = Kvist.whatGender(Kvist.gender);
    // Snoop.gender = Snoop.whatGender(Snoop.gender);
    // Greta.gender = Greta.whatGender(Greta.gender);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, the Instance variable `gender` of `Dog` is missing.
And the `whatGender` Method could be recoded:

```
public String whatGender(final String gender) {
    if (gender == "yes") {
        return "Male";
    } else {
        return "Female";
    }
}
```

...and I wonder quite what you were trying to achieve with that Method?

But anyway, just taking the question "as is", you could do this:

```
Stream.of(Kvist, Snoop, Greta).forEach(dog -> dog.gender = dog.whatGender(dog.gender));
```

...but there's a bit too much `dog.gender` going on there.

Comment: Thanks mate. I didn't have any purpose with the code other than trying to understand the syntax of java. Just started following a course today and was playing around. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ja men saa maa du har det godt deroppe i min gammle hjem. Og hvis du har lust, taenke paa at stemme for min loesning :-)